# Remote code execution and XSS vulnerabilities. What steps should be taken to secure a server once these are discovered and patched?

Tags: security, xss

I've just been notified of a remote code execution vulnerability and an xss vulnerability on a site that I run. I've fixed the responsible code, but I'm wondering what steps should be taken afterwards to:

1. Ensure the server is secure
2. Ensure no data was compromised
3. Ensure no malicious files were uploaded.

The remote code execution vulnerability was particularly bad and allowed any PHP code to be run on the server and output displayed to the user.

The app is hosted on Amazon Lightsail. Would it be helpful to redeploy on a new instance?

Answer (score 0):

Well, definitely ensure that the vulnerabilities have been successfully patched. Remember that block lists are particularly not effective when it comes to patching XSS and RCE.

With regards to XSS, do not display any user input in places like links, iframe sources, and basically not within any elements. Exceptions can be made for displaying it in input boxes. Always put user input through `htmlspecialchars()` (or a similar function for whatever server-side language you're using, which I assume is PHP judging by your question).

If the vulnerabilities were found by you, or someone reported them to you, it's pretty likely no data has been compromised. Big companies find vulnerabilities regularly.

With regards to preventative measures, simply check for more vulnerabilities and ensure they do not exist and also harden your server. You can even use a firewall or other security software which won't patch the vulnerabilities but might block malicious payloads and log them which will both allow you to see the vulnerability exists and also prevent it from being exploited.

You can't really ensure no malicious files were uploaded if it were exploited. I would definitely recommend restoring to a secure backup so long as that does not affect your site negatively.